# How do transactions help resilience to system failure?

Tags: transaction

I understand transactions were developed to meet two requirements:

1. Concurrent DB access
2. Resilience to system failures

I understand how the concurrency issue is motivated; to overcome the database consistency problem.

However, I have a question:  How do transactions help system resilience to failures?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, the "resilience to system failure" is handled by the server to ensure that the transaction either:

1. Succeeds in committing the transaction.

Or:

2. Ensures that a non-committed transaction rolls back to the previous state.

In other words, the transaction completes successfully or else (in a failure) all the in-flight changes are undone since the transaction is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

One common answer to this question is to examine how a bank transfer might work.

Transferring money from account A to account B will have at least two distinct processes:

```
Account A decreases total
Account B increases total
```

If the system were to fail after the first process completed, and each separate process committed the data, then account A would be decreased and account B wouldn't be increased.  The money would be effectively "lost".

Wrapping this in a transaction means that both processes must succeed for the transaction to be committed.  It is not possible for money to be "lost".